# QTabWidget Hide and Show tabs

Tags: c++, qt

I have some problems with QTabWidget. In case of the missing Hide functionality I have to build my own.  According to the documentation I use removeTab and insertTab, but with insert Tab I have a problem to show the Tab page that is removed.

I use to add

```
  RibbonTabContent *ribbonTabContent = new RibbonTabContent;
  QTabWidget::addTab(ribbonTabContent, tabIcon, tabName);
```

To remove  is use:

```
void Ribbon::hideTab(const QString &tabName)
{
  // Find ribbon tab
  for (int i = 0; i < count(); i++)
  {
    if (tabText(i).toLower() == tabName.toLower())
    {
       QTabWidget::removeTab(i);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Both functions are working, pWidget is always null. But now the insert function do not work well. I think there I have a problem, but do not understand my problem.

```
void Ribbon::showTab(const QString &tabName){

    // Find ribbon tab
    QWidget* pWidget= QTabWidget::findChild<RibbonTabContent *>(tabName);
    if(pWidget){
        QTabWidget::insertTab(2,pWidget, tabName);
    }
}
```

Maybe someone can help me out?

Comment: What does "does not work well" mean? Does it mean "does nothing", "causes flickering", "causes exception"?

Comment: To hide your tab, you delete its content. Then the showTab method cannot find it. You need to use QWidget::set Visible on the RibbonTabContent

Comment: Nico238 No! Please read the documentation, removeTab do not delete the page.

Comment: The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#removeTab) is pretty clear, the tab object is not deleted, sure, but it's still removed from the children of the `QTabWidget`, so `QTabWidget::findChild` obviously can't find that tab.

Comment: SilvanoCerza. The page object still exits and is what the insertTab need. I think then the findChild is used wrong? How to find the page widget in the collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `QTabWidget::removeTab` you remove the tab at the specified index from the children tree of your `QTabWidget`, the tab instance is not actually deleted though, so when you search for that same tab with `QTabWidget::findChild` you can't find it because it's not a child of your `QTabWidget` anymore. From the code you show I think you probably would not find it anyway since `findChild` searches for a widget with the specified `objectName` but you never set it for your tab.

A solution would be to store the removed tabs and then restore them when you please.

Assuming `m_hiddenTabs` is a `QHash<QString, QWidget*>` or `QMap<QString, QWidget*>` you could try something like this.

```
void Ribbon::hideTab(const QString &tabName)
{
  // Find ribbon tab
  for (int i = 0; i < count(); i++)
  {
    if (tabText(i).toLower() == tabName.toLower())
    {
       m_hiddenTabs.insert(tabName.toLower(), QTabWidget::widget(i));
       QTabWidget::removeTab(i);
       break;
    }
  }
}

void Ribbon::showTab(const QString &tabName){

    // Find ribbon tab
    auto tab = m_hiddenTabs.take(tabName.toLower());
    if(tab){
        QTabWidget::insertTab(2, tab, tabName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Qt 5.15 it is also possible to use [`setTabVisible`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#setTabVisiblehttps://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#setTabVisible):

```
void QTabWidget::setTabVisible(int index, bool visible)
```

> If visible is true, the page at position index is visible; otherwise the page at position index is hidden. The page's tab is redrawn appropriately.If visible is true, the page at position index is visible; otherwise the page at position index is hidden. The page's tab is redrawn appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunate that QTabBar is unable to 'hide' a tab.

Here is my very easy work-around: mark the tabs 'disabled' instead (e.g. `ui->tabWidget->setTabEnabled(tabIndex, false);`).

Then, use stylesheets to style the "disabled" tab as entirely invisible and taking up no space:

```
QTabBar::tab:disabled
{
    min-width: 0px;
    max-width: 0px; 
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

This works near-perfectly for me, with the only downside being that you can't have both disabled and "hidden" tabs in the same tabbar. However, usually I want one or the other, not both in the same bar.